# Get error in Omron PLC NBdesigner program when trying to run macro c code

Tags: database, compiler-errors, macros, plc

Can someone help me please,
I want to use macro c in nbdesigner for create special function that I will use in HMI but when I try to compile macro code I get error message "failed to compile PTHMI0!". How can I solve this error?

Comment: Have you already tried [this](https://forums.mrplc.com/index.php?/topic/34762-nb-designer-failed-to-compile-logo/)? Here it looks like it's a problem with the logo, but in your case it could be for another cause still related to the long path.